# Can a wordpress user keep logged in another server?

Tags: wordpress

I have a woprpress site and need the user automatically login in another server no wordpress when he will visite that site. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookie or session or etc...
With this data you can run auto login function.
My example:

```
function auto_login() {
    // this works perfectly
    $user_login = 'admin';

    // this does not work even when setting the same variable via query string ?user=admin
    // $user_login = $_GET['user'];

    //get user's ID
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
    $user_id = $user->ID;

    //login
    wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
}
add_action('init', 'auto_login');
```